# QTP UFT Unable to find row count from table

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I was not able to find row count of that table and when I spy, Object Respository doesn't show any webtable. Can you please help me on how to find the row count. It was developed in Angular Js framewrok.

**Attached Object Repsoitory:**
[image]

**The DOM**
[image: UI Elements]

Comment: As you can clearly see (using object spy), there is no WebTable available. Can you post the source code of the page...?

Comment: I attached Image link above (Click Here for UI Elements)

Comment: What is the UFT and Angular JS version?

Comment: @y_r_k it's 1.4

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the screenshot do not contain a `TABLE` element (only `DIV`s). 
Try running (in the browser's developer tools) `document.getElementsByTagName('table')` if it returns an empty set then this is the reason UFT isn't showing you a table.

UFT does not recognise Angular tables since they are non-standard. You can add support using [WebExtensibility](http://www.advancedqtp.com/DemoMTW/content/tech.web_ext.html).

Comment: I use Web and Java Addin's all the time but it still doesn't recognize anything.

Comment: He's talking about the Extensibility toolkits, not about the add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

to get the row count from the table (not simple table its a grid)

```
Set objDesc = Description.Create
objDesc("micclass").value = "WebElement"
objDesc("class Name").value = "ui-gri-row.*"

Set ObjRows = Browser("").Page("").WebElement("class:=ui-grid-canvas").ChildObjects(objDesc)

msgbox "Row Count : " & objRows.Count
```