# QTP UFT How to find a row number and column number? Angular JS

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

When I spy the table it shows just browser - Page - WebElement and also UI is developed in Angular JS.

I there any way to find row number and column number? By the way I am using UFT/QTP

[image]

[image]

Comment: Will you be able to share HTML source code?

Comment: Added HTML code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QTP UFT Unable to find row count from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228460/qtp-uft-unable-to-find-row-count-from-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source-code's image which you have attached, it is quite evident that the webElement corresponding to the **rows** have class = "ui-grid-row ng-scope". So, you can make use of descriptive programming. I assume that you already have added the object `Browser(...).Page(...)` to your OR.

```
Set rowDesc = Description.Create
rowDesc("Class Name").value = "WebElement"
rowDesc("Class").value = "ui-grid-row ng-scope"
Set objRows = Browser(...).Page(...).ChildObjects(rowDesc)
rowCount = objRows.Count                             'This variable should now contain the total number of rows"
```

Now, this is just an idea which you can give a try. If it works for you, you can further enhance it to get the column count. If there is no way you can get the column count, then you can get the total cell count using the same method. In that case, you just need to change the value of property "class" to the one mentioned in the Object Spy Image("`ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope`"). Now you have Row Count and Cell Count. To get the column count, you can divide cell count by row count.(Again, this will give you correct answer ONLY IF there are same number of columns for each of tbe rows).

Comment: Thats great. Even for the column count?

Comment: Yes sir. I have done what you have told exactly for column count.